# slapd process memory consumption

Tags: openldap, virtual-memory

I am adding and deleting configuration from LDAP, and there is an increase in VmRSS and VmSize of slapd process, both, in case of configuration addition and configuration deletion.
My question is
  Does increase in  VmSize/VmRSS when configuration is deleted from LDAP conclusively indicate a memory leak in LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

Most unlikely. It's been in existence for decades and has millions of sites. However few if any programs that grow in memory ever release it back to the operating system. This has more to do with how C libraries are written than with specific applications.

Comment: If memory is never released to the operating system , then would not it result in sytem running out of memory eventually? The system on which I am using LDAP is highly available, and the configuration addition and deletion will keep happening for days together. In such a scenario, I am afraid, we can run out of memory going by the VmRSS/VmSize trend

Comment: It would indeed, if processes have memory leaks and unbounded heaps. In general they don't.